# Php redirect with http authentication

Tags: php, http, authentication, redirect, http-authentication

How to redirect to a url and pass through in php the login and password http, ie, the http basic login but without user interference? without login pop-ups !

thanks,
celso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't.

Redirecting to http://user:pass@example.com/ will work on some browsers but not all.

You could use a substitute authentication module, and push a value into it - e.g. using [mod_authmemcookie](http://authmemcookie.sourceforge.net/) on Apache if you're happy to tweak the server config like this (and have a cookie you can use).

Answer (score 1):

don't know if i understood you right, but if you only want to redirect to a http-auth-secured site without the annoying popup, you can sent the username and password in the url:

```
http://username:password@exapmle.com/adminpanel/
```

note that, with this solution, the password is readable in the url and some browsers (IE only <=6, this was disabled in the newer versions) don't support this - maybe thats a problem for you. for more information, take a look at [this article](http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2008/05/19/http-authentication-in-a-url/)

Answer (score 0):

With basic auth, the browser will re-send credentials when requested by the server.  This only works for the same hostname though.